# Cloning a HDD that has an "Invalide node structure"

Tags: disk-cloning

If I clone a HDD that has an "Invalide node structure" (or other type of error, for that matter), will the error follow with the data?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

If the data on a hard drive contains a file system in an invalid state, that invalid state will carry over if you exactly copy the contents over using an image utility.  This is assuming you are using an imaging utility that reads the source device sector by sector and then writes the target device sector by sector.

If you are using a utility that instead reads the filesystem and creates something more like an archive (such as WIM format), it will likely fail with an error when you try to read the source device.

Comment: Doh!! Any suggestions to recover the data (FYI mac user)? Would a tidiest copy/paste (about 1Tb of data!!!) do the trick?